# Do I use eigen values from common factor solution OR from the original matrix? EFA in R, polychoric

Tags: r, factor-analysis, eigenvalues, polychoric

I'm currently running an EFA in r, using the cor = "poly" setting with principal axis factoring, and am trying to determine the eigenvalues of the analysis.

I am getting two different sets of values: 1) values = Eigen values of the common factor solution; 2) e.values = Eigen values of the original matrix.

I'm fairly new to factor analysis in r, and so I'm having a hard time understanding what the difference between the common factor solution and original matrix are, could anyone please clear this up for me?

I'm wondering if the e.values (from the original matrix) are obtained by using SMC for estimating commonalities, and then the values (from the common factor solution) assumes the communality of every variable is 1. Since I'm conducting an exploratory factor analysis I'm thinking it's best to use the values obtained by using SMC, however this is just my guess to what is happening, so if anyone could help explain this I would appreciate it a lot!

Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to CV! It would help readers to know a little bit more detail about your question. For example, can you define EFA and what packages you are using in R. I believe you are some sort of Factor Analysis, can you confirm? Also, what is meant by SMC?

Comment: Doing extraction of factor loadings out of polychoric matrix P means you are on its rails now, from the beginning. Forget about original correlatoins C. You decide on the number of factors by doing scree plot of eigenvalues of P. Then you set the initial communalities as SMC of P and do the extraction.